# Invoking Integer.parseInt method using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, methods

how can I call a parseInt function on some variable ?  I want to do something like
parseInt.invoke("23");

Note : I have an array of methods where parseInt is stored

```
Method[] methods contains the parseInt method
```

so... it's like
      methods[0].invoke("23");

but when i do this i get

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at myproject.MyProject.main(MyProject.java:114)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29) takes the first argument as the object on which this method is invoked, and 2<sup>nd</sup> argument onwards, it takes the arguments of the method. First argument has to be a reference for an *instance method*, and simply `null` for a `static` method. Since [`Integer#parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) is a `static` method. The first argument to the `invoke` method has to be `null` for that:

```
methods[0].invoke(null, "23");
```

Comment: still getting the  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments error

Comment: @fadytaher Check if `method[0]` is really the `Integer#parseInt` method?

Comment: System.out.println("THIS PARSE FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED :"+m.get(0).getName());             
                System.out.print(m.get(0).invoke(null,"25"));

Comment: @fadytaher So what did you get as output?

Comment: THIS PARSE FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED :parseInt then the error

Comment: @fadytaher: I don't know how you're getting that array of methods, but if you really have a reference to the `Method` instance for `Integer.parseInt`, Rohit's `invoke` call works correctly: http://pastie.org/8718711 The results you quote suggest you're getting some *other* `parseInt` method, not `Integer.parseInt`. Live copy: http://ideone.com/qVWlib

Comment: @fadytaher If that's the `parseInt` method from `Integer` class, that takes a single `String` argument, then the invocation cannot fail. Have you got the overloaded version that takes a radix as argument also?

Comment: @fadytaher Try this - `methods[0].invoke(null, "23", 10);`. It should work, if the other one fails.

Comment: i guess the radix worked , with the parseInt , the problem now that I have other functions that will be called like parseFloat... which seems not to take radix as arguement because i got an error there , also i want to mention that the program is running fine in the debug mode

Comment: @fadytaher: If using the radix worked, you're getting the overload. So get the right function, by using the right arguments with `getMethod` (rather than using `getMethods`).

Answer (score -1):

Is method[0] returning the parseInt method of Integer class ?
May be this will help you :-

```
 Method m =Integer.class.getMethod("parseInt", String.class);
 System.out.println(m.invoke(null, "23"));
```

String.class is parameter passing to parseInt i.e "23"